# Why doesn't OracleDataAdapter.Fill work with this Natural Join SQL Statement

Tags: vb.net, odp.net-managed

I am having trouble getting certain SQL statements containing Natural Joins to work with OracleDataAdapter.Fill(). I am using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess 4.121.1.0.

To illustrate this, review the following valid SQL statements. All work properly in a SQL editor. However, the last one does not work via ODP.NET when I use the OracleDataAdaper.Fill method. I have not had any trouble using a OracleDataReader with any of these statements.

Works with OracleDataAdapter.Fill

```
SELECT *
  FROM Operation_Settings, Settings
 WHERE     Settings.Setting_ID = Operation_Settings.Setting_ID
```

Works with OracleDataAdapter.Fill

```
SELECT * FROM (Operation_Settings NATURAL JOIN Settings)
```

Does Not work with OracleDataAdapter.Fill

```
SELECT * FROM Operation_Settings NATURAL JOIN Settings
```

Exception Message:

> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00942: table or
>   view does not exist

**Data Access Layer function performing DB lookup and fetch**

```
Public Function GetQueryResults(parameters As Dictionary(Of String, Object), query As String, connectionString As String) As DataTable

    Using table As New DataTable

        Using conn As New OracleConnection(connectionString)

            Using cmd = CreateOracleCommand(query, parameters, conn)

                Using adapter As New OracleDataAdapter(cmd)

                    adapter.Fill(table)

                    Return table

                End Using ' adapter
            End Using ' cmd
        End Using ' conn
    End Using ' table

End Function
```

I am open to any ideas and will upload any additional info you require.